# JSF Datatable and SelectBooleanCheckBox

Tags: jsf

I have a scenario where I have to give an option to the user to select Applications and its related Profiles. The user should select at least one Application and One Profile and he can also select more than one. Each Application has its own Profiles and there can be multiple applications. My UserBean has a List of ApplicationVO and that ApplicationVO has isSelected (boolean), application id (int), application name(String) and Profile List. That Profile list has List of ProfileVO and ProfileVO has isSelected(boolean), profile id(int) and Profile name(String).

I am new to JSF and tried to use datatable and SelectBooleanCheckBox which works fine. But at this point I am not sure how to validate and display the error message in the same JSP with the remaining user entered data intact. Also I am not sure how to update the bean with the options checked/unchecked by the user.

When the user clicks Submit my validations should be:

1. At least one application should be selected
2. If an application is selected, at least one profile should be selected
3. Profile check boxes should be disabled until the application is selected
4. When the user unchecks the application check box, profiles check box should be disabled.

I have the following code. Please help me and can also suggest me if there are any other best way to accomplish the same.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{UserBean.applicationList}" var="appList">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Applications" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{appList.isSelected}" label="#{appList.applicationName}"/>
        <h:outputText value="#{appList.applicationName}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header" >
            <h:outputText value="Profiles" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:dataTable value="#{appList.profileList}" var="profileList">
            <h:column>
                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{profileList.isSelected}" />
                <h:outputText value="#{profileList.profileName}" />
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: I am really stuck up on this. If anyone can help me out I would really appreciate that. Thanks

Comment: @Solomon: **Welcome to StackOverflow!** Mmmm, seems that you want to say `#{profileList.selected}` (without the `is`). I will take a better look later.

Comment: Since the ProfileVO has the property named "isSelected" I gave the same name in the JSP which is working. I am stucked on the validation and how to pass back the selected user input to the bean. I selected checkbox as it looks good in the UI but if I cannot use that control to fulfil my requirement, I am open to other controls and design.

Comment: I am not getting any idea to proceed further. I really need some help in this. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement by validating in the bean and was able to get the selected values from the ApplicationList